# mosquitto is loaded but not running after command:sudo brew services start mosquitto

Tags: homebrew, mosquitto

my problem is it's not running!

```
hanpeng@hanpeng ~ % sudo brew services stop mosquitto
Stopping mosquitto... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped mosquitto (label: homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto)
hanpeng@hanpeng ~ % sudo brew services start mosquitto
==> Successfully started mosquitto (label: homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto)
hanpeng@hanpeng ~ % sudo brew services info mosquitto
mosquitto (homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto)
Running: ✘
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
```

why it's just connot running. and the version of mosquitto is as below

```
hanpeng@hanpeng ~ % brew upgrade mosquitto
Warning: mosquitto 2.0.14 already installed
```

Comment: What do the logs say? Have you tried running it manually?